# indicator system monitor showing icon instead of text

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, indicator, panel

My indicator system monitor showing a blank icon instead of a text on my panel:

[image: here's the screenshot]

When I hover the icon it shown system info like CPU usage, memory usage, swap,etc.

Is there some config I should tweak or am I missing something?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your preferences screen

Comment: which preferences screen? panel's or indicator-sysmoitor's?

Comment: Indicator-sysmonitor's preferences

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dYC2uWu.png

Comment: Indicator-sysmonitor looks to be set up properly. On my Unity Desktop that works but I'm not using Xfce Desktop so can't test it there. Hopefully an Xubuntu user reads your question and can add more.